# Turning around at the edges of a world (Java)

Tags: java, object

I'm trying to get an object to wander around the world randomly. 
This object has a 25% chance of turning left, 25% chance of turning right, and 50% chance of moving straight.
I have to ensure that the random direction chosen is not one that will take the object out of bounds. I used `getGridX()` and `getGridY()` to check the current object's coordinate position to determine if it is at the edge. And I've only actively considered 2 of the corners of the world.
However, it keeps getting forced outside the world.

What is my code doing wrong?

```
import sofia.micro.*;

import sofia.util.Random;

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------

public class Food extends SimpleActor
{

    //~ Constructor ...........................................................

    /**
     * Creates a new Food object.
     */
    public Food()
    {
        super();
    }


    //~ Methods ...............................................................

    // ----------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * 25% chance of turning left 
     * 25% chance of turning right
     * 50% chance of moving forward
     */
    public void act()
    {
        int value = Random.generator().nextInt(100);
        this.changeDirection();
        if (value < 25)
        {
            this.turn(LEFT);
            this.changeDirection();
        }
        else if (value < 50)
        {
            this.turn(RIGHT);
            this.changeDirection();
        }
        else
        {
            this.move();
            this.changeDirection();
        }
    }
    /**
     * make a U-turn
     */
    public void turnAround()
    {
        this.turn(RIGHT);
        this.turn(RIGHT);
    }
    /**
     * detects edge condition and moves away
     */
    public void changeDirection()
    {
        if ((this.getGridY() == this.getWorld().getHeight()) || 
        (this.getGridX() == this.getWorld().getWidth()))
        {
            this.turnAround();
            this.move();
        }
          if ((this.getGridY() == 0) || (this.getGridX() == 0))
        {
            this.turnAround();
            this.move();
        }
        if ((this.getGridY() == this.getWorld().getHeight()) && 
        (this.getGridX() == this.getWorld().getWidth()))
        {
            this.turnAround();
            this.move();
        }
          if ((this.getGridY() == 0) && (this.getGridX() == 0))
        {
            this.turnAround();
            this.move();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the following condition is written twice.  If you're facing out of bounds, wouldn't you do a 360, instead of a 180?  I would remove the latter 2 if statements.

```
if ((this.getGridY() == this.getWorld().getHeight()) && 
(this.getGridX() == this.getWorld().getWidth()))
{
    this.turnAround();
    this.move();
}
```

Comment: I'm starting to figure out how to add in something that checks for the direction that the object is facing. I'm going to try adding an if statement for that in the turnAround () method.
Also, if I remove the latter 2 if statements, how would I ensure that it wouldn't fall out of bounds when at the southeast corner and the at the (0,0)? I mean, it falls off regardless as it is, but I think once I've gotten the direction statements added, it should fix everything. There's a getDirection () method that returns the compass direction IT is currently facing (NORTH, SOUTH, EAST, or WEST).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `turn()` method is properly implemented (I don't see it in your code), here is one problem I found:

```
if (value < 25)
{
    this.turn(LEFT);
    this.changeDirection();
}
else if (value < 50)
{
    this.turn(RIGHT);
    this.changeDirection();
}
else
{
    this.move();            //  < --- You shouldn't be using this here
    this.changeDirection();
}
```

Remove that line. Because when this statement is reached, it is possible that your actor is in an edge and facing into emptiness - and you are literally telling it to move forward.

Instead, remove the line and just call `changeDirection()`, which will cause the actor to turn 180 degrees. I see that `changeDirection()` will also cause the actor move, so basically your actor will move away from the edge.

Comment: You're right, I cleaned up my code so as to avoid repetitive actions. But it still gets forced out of bounds when I run it. I feel like it's because I'm not implementing any method that considers the direction it's facing.